# How to make a column with lists from columns of list elements in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like

```
  test = pd.DataFrame([[['P','N'], ['Z', 'P']],[['N','N'], ['Z', 'P']]],  
  columns=['c1', 'c2'])
```

I want to add another column `c3` to test whose elements are

```
['PZ', 'NP']
['NZ', 'NP']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = test.assign(c3 = [[x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]] for x,y in test.values.tolist()])
```

Or:

```
df = test.assign(c3 = list(map(list,zip(test.c1.str[0]+test.c2.str[0],test.c1.str[1]+test.c2.str[1]))))

print(df)
       c1      c2        c3
0  [P, N]  [Z, P]  [PZ, NP]
1  [N, N]  [Z, P]  [NZ, NP]
```

---

```
print([[x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]] for x,y in test.values.tolist()])
[['PZ', 'NP'], ['NZ', 'NP']]

print(list(map(list,zip(test.c1.str[0]+test.c2.str[0],test.c1.str[1]+test.c2.str[1]))))
[['PZ', 'NP'], ['NZ', 'NP']]
```

Comment: thanks! was just wondering if there is any sensible way to avoid the loop? maybe for better performance..